# trouble in overriding JFrame.setBackground()

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception

I have a class called MainUI that extends JFrame, it has this code :

```
//Constructor
public MainUI(){

// components/panels are already defined and initialized here.

setBackground(Color.decode("#EFF4E4"));
}

@Override
public void setBackground(Color colorbg){ //a method to set the same background color for all the components I ave

getContentPane().setBackground(colorbg);

decisionPanel.setBackground(colorbg);

adbRadio.setBackground(colorbg);
fastbootRadio.setBackground(colorbg);
commandRadio.setBackground(colorbg);

pushPanel.setBackground(colorbg);
uninstallPanel.setBackground(colorbg);
pcPanel.setBackground(colorbg);
phonePanel.setBackground(colorbg);
}
```

however, when I compile, it gives a NullPointerException at the line [ decisionPanel.setBackground(colorbg); ]

I tried not overriding the setBackground method and renamed it and the code worked fine, I don't know why overriding setBackground method causes a problem?

**I'm sure all the panels/components are initialized before the call to the method, it's obvious since the code did work just ater I've renamed the method.**

Comment: are  you sure decisionPanel is correctly initialized when you try to set the BG?

Comment: I don't see where you create decisionPanel.

Comment: Most likely because setBackground is called when constructing a `JFrame` (prior to your `//defining components/panels`)

Comment: Also, it is almost always a better idea to have your class extend JPanel rather than JFrame, then your main() creates a JFrame, instantiates your class and adds that to the JFrame.

Comment: yes i'm sure all components are initialized, also it's obvious since I said that the code worked fine when I just renamed the method.

Comment: *"also it's obvious"*, No, it's not. `// components/panels are already defined and initialized here.` Well, maybe there is where your problem lies on. For better help sooner, please post a [mcve]

Comment: `es i'm sure all components are initialized`  Read my comment above - setBackground is being called in the parent constructor (called automatically) before any code is executed in your constructor

Comment: if that actually the case, it would be the answer then. @copeg

Comment: It would have helped if you showed the real code - you show `public MainUI(){` as the declaration of your class, and then show a call to setBackground(). That should not cause any problems (nor should setBackground() be being called anywhere else), since your declaration did NOT specify that mainUI is a subclass of JFrame or JPanel.

Comment: @FredK it's the constructor not the class declaration, I can't post other contents of the constructor because it's kinda big

Comment: If it is big, then strip out unrelated code to the problem, as discussed in making a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a snip of code  from JFrame class it is really doing the unrecommended call of overridable method from constructor what happens is that your overridden version is executed before your class has been created "and before your fields are initialized and their is no way to initialize your fields before the super's constructor finishes its work" so you have few options either avoid referring to your subclass fields in the overridden method/s or do what you did by making new method to do the stuff you want

```
public JFrame(String title, GraphicsConfiguration gc) {
        super(title, gc);
        frameInit();
    }

    /** Called by the constructors to init the <code>JFrame</code> properly. */
    protected void frameInit() {
        enableEvents(AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK | AWTEvent.WINDOW_EVENT_MASK);
        setLocale( JComponent.getDefaultLocale() );
        setRootPane(createRootPane());
        setBackground(UIManager.getColor("control"));
        setRootPaneCheckingEnabled(true);
        if (JFrame.isDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated()) {
            boolean supportsWindowDecorations =
            UIManager.getLookAndFeel().getSupportsWindowDecorations();
            if (supportsWindowDecorations) {
                setUndecorated(true);
                getRootPane().setWindowDecorationStyle(JRootPane.FRAME);
            }
        }
        sun.awt.SunToolkit.checkAndSetPolicy(this);
    }
```

or you can override the `frameInit()`

```
@Override
    protected void frameInit() {
        //initialize your fields here 
        super.frameInit();
    }
```